# Normal distribution for a given range of numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, statistics

My question is about estimating a normal distribution for a row of points of an interval that are extracted from the data, just knowing the maximum = 200 and minimum = 100, to distribute them randomly by an average and an associated standard deviation that we will estimate. Is there a method in Matlab, or the literature to do it, such that when you draw the associated law; we must not exceed the min and max values I used this trick there:

```
x = xmin + rand (1, n) * (xmax-xmin);
```

but I do not know how to extract the parameters of the normal distribution (the mean, the standard deviation).
I'm looking for the mean and the std.

Comment: Your "trick" is not really a trick, it is code to produce a uniformly distributed random sample between `xmin` and `xmax`. It is not a normally distributed random sample. Please [edit] your post to explain where you need to extract the parameters from. Are you looking for the functions `mean` and `std`?

Comment: Exactly i'm looking for mean and std